# how to "poll" python multiprocess pool apply_async

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool, apply-async

I have a task function like this:

```py
def task (s) :
    # doing some thing
    return res
```

The original program is:

```py
res = []
for i in data :
    res.append(task(i))
    # using pickle to save res every 30s
```

I need to process a lot of data and I don't care the output order of the results. Due to the long running time, I need to save the current progress regularly. Now I'll change it to multiprocessing

```py
pool = Pool(4)
status = []
res = []
for i in data :
    status.append(pool.apply_async(task, (i,))

for i in status :
    res.append(i.get())
    # using pickle to save res every 30s
```

Supposed I have processes p0,p1,p2,p3 in Pool and 10 task, (task(0) .... task(9)). If p0 takes a very long time to finish the task(0).

1. Does the main process be blocked at the first "res.append(i.get())" ?
2. If p1 finished task(1) and p0 still deal with task(0), will p1 continue to deal with task(4) or later ?
3. If the answer to the first question is yes, then how to get other results in advance. Finally, get the result of task (0)

---

I update my code but the main process was blocked somewhere while other process were still dealing tasks. What's wrong ? Here is the core of code

```
       with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(4) as ex :
            for i in self.inBuffer :
                futuresList.append(ex.submit(warpper, i))
            
            for i in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futuresList) :
                (word, r) = i.result()
                self.resDict[word] = r
                self.logger.info("{} --> {}".format(word, r))
                cur = datetime.now()
                if (cur - self.timeStmp).total_seconds() > 30 :
                    self.outputPickle()
                    self.timeStmp = datetime.now()
```

The length of `self.inBuffer` is about 100000. `self.logger.info` will write the info to a log file. For some special input i, the `wrapper` function will print auxiliary information with print. `self.resDict` is a dict to store result. `self.outputPickle()` will write a .pkl file using `pickle.dump`

At first, the code run normally, both the update of log file and `print` by `warpper`. But at a moment, I found that the log file has not been updated for a long time (several hours, the time to complete a warper shall not exceed 120s), but the `warpper` is still printing information(Until I kill the process it print about 100 messages without any updates of log file). Also, the time stamp of the output .pkl file doesn't change. Here is the implementation of `outputPickle()`

```
    def outputPickle (self) :
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(self.wordDir, self.outFile)) :
            if os.path.exists(os.path.join(self.wordDir, "{}_backup".format(self.outFile))):
                os.remove(os.path.join(self.wordDir, "{}_backup".format(self.outFile)))
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(self.wordDir, self.outFile), os.path.join(self.wordDir, "{}_backup".format(self.outFile)))
        
        with open(os.path.join(self.wordDir, self.outFile), 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(self.resDict, f)
```

Then I add three `print`function :

```
                print("getting res of something")
                (word, r) = i.result()
                print("finishing i.result")
                self.resDict[word] = r
                print("finished getting res of {}".format(word))
```

Here is the log:

```
getting res of something
finishing i.result
finished getting res of CNICnanotubesmolten
getting res of something
finishing i.result
finished getting res of CNN0
getting res of something
message by warpper
message by warpper
message by warpper
message by warpper
message by warpper
```

The log "message by warpper" can be printed at most once every time the warpper is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes, as processes are submitted asynchronously. Also `p1` (or other) will take another chunk of data if the size of the input iterable is larger than the *max* number of processes/workers
3. *"... how to get other results in advance"*

   One of the convenient options is to rely on [`concurrent.futures.as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed) which will return the results as they are completed:

---

```
import time
import concurrent.futures


def func(x):
    time.sleep(3)
    return x ** 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = range(1, 5)
    results = []

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(4) as ex:
        futures = [ex.submit(func, i) for i in data]
        # processing the earlier results: as they are completed
        for fut in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            res = fut.result()
            results.append(res)
            print(res)
```

---

Sample output:

```
4
1
9
16
```

---

Another option is to use `callback` on `apply_async(func[, args[, kwds[, callback[, error_callback]]]])` call; the callback accepts only single argument as the returned result of the function. In that callback you can process the result in minimal way (considering that it's tied to only a single argument/result from a concrete function). The general scheme looks as follows:

```
def res_callback(v):
    # ... processing result
    with open('test.txt', 'a') as f:  # just an example
        f.write(str(v))
    print(v, flush=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = range(1, 5)
    results = []
    with Pool(4) as pool:
        tasks = [pool.apply_async(func, (i,), callback=res_callback) for i in data]
        # await for tasks finished
```

But that schema would still require to somehow **await** (`get()` results) for submitted tasks.

Comment: I update my code but the main process was blocked somewhere while other process were still dealing tasks. What's wrong ? I update it in my question

Comment: @arron, try to comment out your logging `# logging....` and see if that changed the flow, if not: check what your function `self.outputPickle()` is doing (that's unclear)

Comment: With that logging, `self.outputPickle()` will not update the output ".pkl" when the main process was 'block'. The time stamp of '.pkl' is nearly the same as the last record in log file. Now I try to comment this logging statement.

Comment: Using print function, it seems that the main process was block at `(word, r) = i.result()`

Comment: if `i.result()` is untimately blocking the main thread, that means that a nominal task is designed with a durable block running